# Unable to select text boxes of an particular column through XPath in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My Java

```
package com.ej.zob.modules;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Revenue_Month {
public void Execute()
{
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("VIEW")).click();
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("REVENUE")).click();
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.name("click")).click();
    List<WebElement> c = LaunchApplication.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'Edit_')]"));
    for(WebElement elem_1:c)
    {
        elem_1.click();
    }
    List<WebElement> w = LaunchApplication.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[position() = count(ancestor::table/tbody/tr/td[.='May']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]"));
    //for(WebElement elem:w)
    //{
    //  elem.
    //  elem.sendKeys("50");
    //  elem.click();
    //}

 }
 }
```

**My HTML**

```
<div id="idshowtable" style="background:#7F4F20">
<table id="mainTable" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="14">State Wise Revenue of a Bank (all Figures are in INR and in Lacs)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State \ Month</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">October</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">November</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">December</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">January</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">February</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">March</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">April</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">May</a>
 </td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">June</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">July</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">August</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">September</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="">Operation</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rajasthan</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_1" type="text" value="51838" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_1")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_2" type="text" value="62192" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_2")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_3" type="text" value="87617" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
 <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_3")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_4" type="text" value="59826" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_4")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>  
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_5" type="text" value="97075" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_5")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_6" type="text" value="58818" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_6")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_7" type="text" value="41250" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_7")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_8" type="text" value="52233" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_8")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_9" type="text" value="74272" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_9")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>  
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_10" type="text" value="28197" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_10")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_11" type="text" value="79977" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_11")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="1_12" type="text" value="11158" style="width:50px" name="U1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("1_12")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<a id="Edit_1" href="#" onclick="fnEditRevenue("1");" style="visibility: hidden;">Edit</a>
|
<a id="Hide_1" href="#" onclick="fnHideRevenue(1);" style="visibility: hidden;">Hide</a>
|
<a id="Show_1" href="#" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="fnShowRevenue(1);">Show</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sikkim</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_1" type="text" value="66503" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_1")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_2" type="text" value="84033" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_2")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_3" type="text" value="37062" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_3")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_4" type="text" value="25780" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_4")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_5" type="text" value="70574" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_5")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td> 
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_6" type="text" value="99017" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_6")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_7" type="text" value="1406" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
 <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_7")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
 <div>
 <input id="2_8" type="text" value="42724" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_8")" style="width:60px">
</div> 
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_9" type="text" value="22180" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
 <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_9")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td> 
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_10" type="text" value="27663" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_10")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_11" type="text" value="88324" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_11")" style="width:60px">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>
<input id="2_12" type="text" value="42853" style="width:50px" name="U2">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="fnUpdateRevenue("2_12")" style="width:60px">
 </div>
</td>
<td>
 <a id="Edit_2" href="#" onclick="fnEditRevenue("2");" style="visibility: hidden;">Edit</a>
|
 <a id="Hide_2" href="#" onclick="fnHideRevenue(2);" style="visibility: hidden;">Hide</a>
|
 <a id="Show_2" href="#" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="fnShowRevenue(2);">Show</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am unable to select the text boxes in a column for a particular month.

```
//td[position() = count(ancestor::table/tbody/tr/td[.='May']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

By this XPath I can select the month name say 'may' and all `tr`s.But I want to select the column and the specific input textboxes only of the intended column using month name.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was little unclear I guess. But, I assume the requirement is to find the column and associated `td` using the name of month. If so, try this:

```
//td[count(//td//a[contains(.,'October')]//.)]
```

**Edit**

Since, you want only the `inputs` with `type='text'` add additional filtering;

```
//td[count(//td//a[contains(.,'October')]//.)]//input[@type='text']
```

Comment: Concatenation,I know but what I want is All text boxes should be selected with its column Name say 'May'.

Comment: Yes,This is correct it is selecting Month Name 'October' and all its td like 'text boxes' and 'button' but if I want to select only 'October' and td 'text boxes' then what to do? You can see on image above.

Comment: Almost Correct, but If I change the Month Name from October to May in above XPath,It is selecting the text boxes of October only and not moving to Text Boxes of May.Why?

Comment: @AbNimkar Please provide me the full html of the table so that I can test it. Create a [gits](https://gist.github.com/) if the html is too much

Comment: i see the problem. But, i do not think that can be done with xpath. But you can pass the number of month like this `//td[7]//input[@type='text']`

Comment: Do not provide credential on post. it's not secure. However, please post a different question if that's not related to this post

Comment: Yes, I know but this credentials are only made for practice purpose only and I already post this question earlier but not get the expected answer.check this post                                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542764/unable-to-upload-image-through-selenium-webdriver/30544010#30544010

Comment: Not getting any error, but Sendkeys() is  not able to upload the image the image.Don't know why?

Comment: It should work if you provide the file with extension